# Equivalent of __func__ (from C) in Python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I want to create some kind of debugging output for python and want to pass the functionname to another function for output.

The only reasonable way I found to do so was:

```
def foobar():
  print 'hello world'

  print foobar.__name__
```

is there something that does the same thing for the current function to improve copy and pasting of that line?

like the C equivalent `printf("%s", __func__)`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[sys._getframe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66062-determining-current-function-name/) can do that:

```
import sys

def foobar():
    print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

Comment: How also print a class it belongs to?

Answer (score 11):

Well, yes, there is a way...

```
print sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
```

You can even make it a function (getting the name of the previous frame):

```
def function_name():
    return sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name
```

Silly example just to show that it works:

```
>>> def bar():
...     return function_name()
... 
>>> bar()
'bar'
```

(Note that the decorator shown in Krumelur's answer is a much better solution to the problem, but it *is* possible to do what you want in Python =)

Comment: I use it to create file names as log output so traces don't help much here, but thank you anyway.

Answer (score 9):

One thing you could try is to create a decorator that does this:

```
def traceme(func):
  def newfunc(*args, **kwargs):
    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
    print func.__name__
    return ret
  return newfunc

@traceme
def foobar():
  print 'hello world'
```

Comment: `__func__` is actually in C99, and it does exactly what you expected it to.

Comment: That is great news, I had completely missed that. Thanks for informing. Answer updated :)

Comment: What you have made is a `decorator`, not an `annotation`.

Comment: @Krumelur I think depending on the context this is way superior, I just don't print the string I get and hence it's not too useful. But a great and creative answer anyway.

Comment: @Krumelur.  Thanks for this bit of code.  Is there a way to print the args and the kwargs in your example?  I have several functions that have a few lines of code wrapped in a try-catch block.  The catch part is much longer than the lines of code and is similar for all the functions.  I'd like to use your example for the try-catch part, but I'd like to print (among other things) the parameters to func when an exception is caught.

Comment: @Bitdiot Yes, why wouldn't you be able to? The code in the answer uses decorators to replace the function implementation. You could easily call the replaced function inside a try/except block. Error handling is actually where I last used this concept.

Comment: excellent! 
added this `print "{} {}".format(func.__name__, args)` for adding arguments to the trace

Comment: This solution doesn't provide the function name like `__func__` does in C. It just prints it directly to the console.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative method as of 2023**

From version 3.5 onwards, we have another alternative to achieve the same using **inspect**

To get the function name (`__func__ equivalent in C`), we can use

```
return inspect.stack()[1][3]
```

We can use this for related requirements such as line number (`__line__ equivalent in C`)

```
return inspect.stack()[1][2]
```

More live elements details can be queried.  (Ref: Official Python Documentation Link for [Inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html).)

**Full Working Code:**

```
import inspect

def get_function_name():
    return inspect.stack()[1][3]

def get_my_name():
    print(get_function_name())

get_my_name()
```

**Output:**

> get_my_name