# How to get the path of a function in Python?

Tags: python

I want to obtain the file path of a function in Python.

How to do it?

For example,

```
import keras.backend as K
y = K.resize_images(x, 2, 2, 'channels_last')
path = function(K.resize_images)
print(path)
#C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py
```

Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759359/equivalent-of-func-from-c-in-python

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use the [`getfile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getfile) function from the [inspect module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) for this purpose.

For example, given the following files:

`inspect-example.py`

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import inspect
import external_def

def foo():
  pass
    
print(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(foo)))
print(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(external_def.bar)))
```

`external_def.py`

```py
def bar():
  pass
```

Executing `inspect_example.py` produces the following output:

```
$ python inspect-example.py
/home/chuckx/code/stackoverflow/inspect-example.py
/home/chuckx/code/stackoverflow/external_def.py
```

Comment: It works. Thank you, chuckx.

For my example, the code is:

print(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(K.resize_images)))

Answer (score 12):

if you want to obtain the path of the file that contains a function you can try the following code, note: this code only works if the object type is 'function'

```py
def get_path(func):  
     if type(func).__name__ == 'function' : 
         return func.__code__.co_filename
     else: 
         raise ValueError("'func' must be a function")
```