# How to get the directory of a function?

Tags: python

For example:

in the file main/main.py

```
import core.fun as f
f.script()
```

and in the file main/core/fun.py:

```
def script():
    f = open('test.txt','r')
```

where a file test.txt is present in the folder main/core/.

If I run main/main.py it will not work because python will search for the file 'test.txt' in the main folder and not in the main/core folder.

And if I call within the function script()

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

It will again return the directory main

Therefore I would like to know how can I find the directory of the function within the function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9271464/what-does-the-file-variable-mean-do

Comment: Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50673566/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-function-in-python